# How to post List of ids as Params in getjson method in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, getjson

Hi all I have a multiselect dropdwon on selection of dropdown i am calling api controller as it is a multiselect dropdown i have a collection of ids to pass to the api..i have been trying a method but i am geting an exception

```
this is what i have been trying


     function GetProducts(obj) {
      var SelProdids = [];
      var selIds = $(obj).val();          
      if (selIds.length > 0) {
         for (var i = 0; i < selIds.length; i++) {
          SelProdids.push(parseInt(selIds[i]));           
          }
        }

     var params = {};
     params.CatIds = SelProdids;


      $.getJSON('http://localhost:6098/api/Marketing/GetProducts', {    CategoryIds:params}, function (key,Products) {

       });
   }


and my api method looks like this

    Public Product GetAllProducts(long[] CategoryIds)
    {
    }
```

but i am geting an exception saying

```
   **Exception**

    {"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","Message":"No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Int64[]' from content with media type ''undefined''."
```

can any one help me solving this...

Answer (score 0):

Since `GetAllProducts` expects `CategoryIds` to be an array you should just pass an array not an object with an array property.

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:6098/api/Marketing/GetProducts', {CategoryIds:SelProdids}, function (key,Products) {
```